# How to redirect in amp html?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I have this code for normal HTML website (redirect in 30 sec)

```
<div id="counter" style="text-align: center;">30</div>
<script>
        setInterval(function() {
            var div = document.querySelector("#counter");
            var count = div.textContent * 1 - 1;
            div.textContent = count;
            if (count <= 0) {
                window.location.href="https://example.com";
            }
        }, 1000);
    </script>
```

But I need this in amp html and I don't find anything on internet.

Comment: for the setInterval you are passing 1000 milli seconds (thats 1 sec), for 30sec you should pass 30*1000

Comment: The point of AMP is to not use javascript. So what you're trying is simply not going to work. A little extra explanation: AMP's goal is to prevent pages from dynamically generating and rather being loaded as-is. This is to improve performance on phones and slower networks. Redirecting thirty seconds after page load would do the exact opposite and goes against AMP's philosophy.

Comment: The philosophy depends on the use you want to give it. It would not be unethical, put it for example on a web type "youtuberepeat".

Answer (score 0):

AMP does not allow custom JavaScript and the closest you will get is using [`amp-bind`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind) (which does not allow access to `window` or `document`).